# PHP SOAP Server response in XML format

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

I'm creating SOAP web service using PHP.

Here is my code..

SoapServer.php

```
    class server{

        public function RegisterComplaint($strInputXml){
            $str = "<RESULT><complaintNo>09865678</complaintNo></RESULT>";
            $arr['RegisterComplaintResult'] = trim($str);
            return $arr;
        }

    }

    $custom_wsdl = 'custom.wsdl';
    $server = new SoapServer($custom_wsdl);


    $server->setClass('server');
    $server->handle();
```

When I call **RegisterComplaint** using Wizdler(chrome extension) I get below result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.Insurer.com/webservices/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:RegisterComplaintResponse>
                <ns1:RegisterComplaintResult>&lt;RESULT&gt;&lt;complaintNo&gt;09865678&lt;/complaintNo&gt;&lt;/RESULT&gt;</ns1:RegisterComplaintResult>
            </ns1:RegisterComplaintResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here I want result in below format(special characters to HTML entities):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.Insurer.com/webservices/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:RegisterComplaintResponse>
                <ns1:RegisterComplaintResult><RESULT><complaintNo>09865678</complaintNo></RESULT></ns1:RegisterComplaintResult>
            </ns1:RegisterComplaintResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Does any one know what I have to change for required output?

I tried html_entity_decode() & htmlspecialchars() on $str variable, but it's not working.

Comment: That 's true, because the `SoapServer` class awaits an object as return value, which will be encoded to xml automatically under the use of the definitions in the wsdl file. A string return will always be encoded. Just use objects.

Comment: Thanks Marcel for your help. It work's now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution as response. (Already quoted out in the comments)

The `SoapServer` class awaits an object as return value. This object will be automatically encoded by the server using the definitions from the used wsdl file. If a string is returned, its entities will always be encoded.

```
class Server
{
    public function registerComplaint()
    {
        $registerComplaintResponse = new stdClass();
        $registerComplaintResult = new stdClass();
        $result = new \stdClass();

        $result->complaintNo = '09865678';
        $registerComplaintResult->RESULT = $result;
        $registerComplaintResponse->RegisterComplaintResult = $registerComplaintResult;

        return $registerComplaintResponse;
    }
}
```

All definitions of return types (complex types) are defined in the wsdl file.